# Sharing URL generation from uuid4?

Tags: python, django, url, sharing

I'm having a bit of a problem figuring out how to generate user friendly links to products for sharing.

I'm currently using `/product/{uuid4_of_said_product}`
Which is working quite fine - but it's a bit user unfriendly - it's kind of long and ugly.

And I do not wish to use and id as it would allow users to "guess" products. Not that that is too much of an issue - I would like to avoid it.

Do you have any hints on how to generate unique, user friendly, short sharing urls based on the unique item id or uuid?

Comment: Are [slugs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug) appropriate for your use case?

Comment: Try doing a search for base62 encoder/decoder libraries. Still guessable but much shorter.

Comment: Greetings raphv - yes slugs are not a possibility as the items in question do not have a title/name or anything that can be slugified.

I apologize for forgetting to mention this from the get go. 

I will look into those Selcuk - thanks.

I did not think of investigation a simple base 64 encode. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Seluck suggested I decided to go with base64 encoding and decoding:

In the model my "link" property is now built from the standard url + `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(media_id))`

The url pattern I use to match the base64 pattern:

`base64_pattern = r'(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$'`

And finally in the view we decode the id to load the proper data:
`media_id = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(str(media_id))`

`media = Media.objects.get(pk=media_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these https://github.com/corpix/shortid and one for django here https://github.com/nebstrebor/django-shortuuidfield